# How is this system in equilibrium?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium, statics

So, after mathematically calculating the answer I found it to be zero. But my teacher says I don't have to do the calculation as this system is in equilibrium and the initial acceleration is zero. But I don't get how is that. Please refer to the question number 8 in this photo.

[image]

Comment: "Both ends are at same levels " think now

Comment: As said, that the system is initially at rest, then it will continue to be at rest until some external force acts on it. Thus the system will remain at rest, if it was a rest initially.

Comment: But gravitational force is acting on it, isn't it?

Comment: See Simon Stevin's (1586) solution at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclined_plane#History.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obvious that the rope is in equilibrium, but in fact it is.

Think of the rope as being in two parts, with length a on the left hand side of the wedge and length b on the right hand side. The rope is uniform, so the mass on the rope on the left hand side is ka and the mass on the right hand side is kb where k is the mass per unit length of the rope.

The forces on the rope on the left hand side are gravity and the normal force from the wedge. The rope does not move perpendicular to the wedge's surface so we only need to resolve forces in a direction parallel to the wedge's surface. The normal force has no component in this direction, and the component of the gravitational force is
$$mg\sin\alpha = kag\sin\alpha$$

Similarly the component of gravitational force parallel to the surface of the wedge on the right hand side is $$kbg\sin\beta$$

and so the net force on the rope is $$kg(a\sin\alpha - b\sin\beta)$$

But because the ends of the rope are at the same level, we know that $a\sin\alpha = b\sin\beta$, so the net force on the rope is zero, and it is indeed in equilibrium.

Without a calculation like this, I don't think it is **obvious** that the rope must be in equilibrium.

Comment: Yes, I was doing it by exact same method but our teacher dismissed it as easy because it was **obvious** that the rope is in equilibrium. But I guess it was probably easier to identify such systems in equilibrium by practicing more questions. Thanks for the help.